# How to fix SAXParseException in route tag when run jar developed using Apache Camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel, maven-assembly-plugin, saxparseexception

Collegues, i have Camel context file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
          http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-2.0.0.xsd">

          <bean id="myFilter" class="com.ac.am.CamelComp.CurrentDateFileFilter"/>
    <bean id="xsdProcessor" class="com.ac.am.CamelComp.MessProcessor"/>
    <bean id="startPolicy" class="org.apache.camel.routepolicy.quartz2.CronScheduledRoutePolicy">
        <property name="routeStartTime" value="0 0/5 * ? * 1-6 *" />
    </bean>

    <camel:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
          <route id="uploadFromFtp" routePolicyRef="startPolicy">
            <camel:from uri="sftp://
            &amp;throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true
            &amp;consumer.delay=10000
            &amp;recursive=true"/>
            <camel:to uri="bean:xsdProcessor"/>
            <camel:to uri="file:sftp-inbound"/>
        </route>
    </camel:camelContext>
</beans>
```

I compiled pogramm using `mvn clean compile assembly:single`.
When i run jar i receive next stack trace:

> [32m13:37:27.923[0;39m [34mINFO [0;39m [32m[main][0;39m
>   [36mo.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader[0;39m : Loading XML bean
>   definitions from class path resource [camel-context.xml]
>   [32m13:37:28.331[0;39m [31mWARN [0;39m [32m[main][0;39m
>   [36mo.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext[0;39m : Exception
>   encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh
>   attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Line 24 in XML document from class path resource [camel-context.xml]
>   is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   lineNumber: 24; columnNumber: 66; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute
>   'routePolicyRef' is not allowed to appear in element 'route'.
>   Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Line 24 in XML document from class path resource [camel-context.xml]
>   is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   lineNumber: 24; columnNumber: 66; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute
>   'routePolicyRef' is not allowed to appear in element 'route'.
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
>           ....
>           at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
>           at com.ac.am.AmeFtp.main(AmeFtp.java:32) Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 24; columnNumber: 66;
>   cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'routePolicyRef' is not allowed to
>   appear in element 'route'.
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processAttributes(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
>           ... 16 more

lineNumber 23 is: 
`<route id="uploadFromFtp" routePolicyRef="startPolicy">`

Could you help to fix it? Thank you.

**UPDATE**

`camel` was added to `route`,  but nothing canges

```
<camel:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
          <camel:route id="uploadFromFtp" routePolicyRef="startPolicy">
            <camel:from uri="sftp:......
            &amp;throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true
            &amp;consumer.delay=10000
            &amp;recursive=true"/>
            <camel:to uri="bean:xsdProcessor"/>
            <camel:to uri="file:sftp-inbound"/>
        </camel:route>
    </camel:camelContext>
```

Stack:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 24; columnNumber: 72; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'routePolicyRef' is not allowed to appear in element 'camel:route'.
```

`lineNumber: 24;` is `<camel:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">`

Comment: You are using an explicit namespace declaration, so it should probably be `<camel:route/>, not just <route/>`.

Comment: @zeppelin, ii didn't help, but thank you.

Comment: The schema for this XML is at http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-1.0.0.xsd.  Note that the definition of the route element does not specify any attributes. So for starters, why dont you just remove the routePolicyRef attribute?

Comment: It looks like zeppelin's answer is the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *camel* namespace
`xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"` is mapped to the 2.0.0 version of the schema http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-2.0.0.xsd (via xsi:schemaLocation), which does not have *routePolicyRef* attribute defined yet.

It looks like this attribute has only been added in [2.1.0](http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-2.1.0.xsd)

```
...
<xs:attribute name="routePolicyRef" type="xs:string"/> 
...
```

hence, the error.

You can probably try to update your *xsi:schemaLocation* to point a proper version of schema (2.1.0 or later), taking that you are using an appropriate version of the framework itself.

Comment: thank you i replace `http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-2.0.0.xsd` with  `http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-2.18.2.xsd` and mistake was fixed.